# Efficiently find OneDrive files with particular extension using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a Dot NET Core (C#/Azure) app that uses Graph API (The NuGet assembly not the REST API directly) to check the OneDrive folders for every employee and process files with a particular extension (For example .docx)

Currently it has a function CheckFolder that calls Graph API to get the child items and, if it's a file then checks the extension. If it's a folder then it recursively calls CheckFolder. This is quite slow where the user has folders with lots of sub-folders.

Is there a faster way to find the particular files? (Please paste in C# examples rather than REST API URLs.)

What I've tried:

1. Using the filter "endswith(name, '.docx')" on the item children but it returns an
   error "Expression cannot be evaluated". startswith doesn't error.
2. Using the SearchWithQ method but even searching client.Drives["X"].Items["root"].SearchWithQ("docx")
   errors with "Expression cannot be evaluated". I've tried the various syntaxes documented for the $search parameter from the REST API but I just get errors.